# Problem with changing the getLineColor property when hovering over a feature?

Tags: reactjs, hover, highlight, layer

As I highlight the border of a Deckgl GeoJsonLayer multipolygon geometry, if it is next to other geometries, that is, they share some sides, I can change the border of those sides that do not have a glued geometry, I attached a picture of what I'm getting:

[image]

with the turf buffer method, but the effect is not as expected, white spaces appear

```
const createBufferedPolygons = (originalPolygons, distance) => {
const bufferedPolygons = turf.buffer(originalPolygons, distance, { units: 'kilometers' });
return bufferedPolygons;
```

};

const bufferedPolygons = createBufferedPolygons(geoJsonData, -0.1);

[image]

Property:

```
const [highlightedId, setHighlightedId] = useState(null);
```

Layer GeoJsonLayer:

```
const geoJsonLayer = new GeoJsonLayer({
id: 'geojson-layer',
data: geoJsonData,
pickable: true,
stroked: true,
filled: true,
opacity: 0.5,
lineWidthScale: 1,
lineWidthMinPixels: 1,
getLineColor: (d) => {
  if (d.properties.cagr === highlightedId) {
    // Resaltar todas las líneas del polígono
    return [0, 0, 0];
  } else {
    // Mantener el color original de las líneas
    return [255, 255, 255];
  }
},
getFillColor: (d) => [128, 0, 255],
onHover,
updateTriggers: {
  getLineColor: [highlightedId],
}
```

});

Hover event:

```
const onHover = ({ x, y, object }) => {
const cagr = object && object?.properties.cagr;
if (cagr !== undefined && highlightedId !== cagr) {console.log(cagr)
  setHighlightedId(cagr);
} else if (cagr === undefined) {
  setHighlightedId(null); // Restablecer el highlightedId si no hay objeto
}
```

};